# Download files from a directory listing

Tags: java, api, download, directory-listing

Is it possible to download all the files from a directory listing? Eg., the following link leads to a listing.

http://www.arthika.net/1234TB/new/Kuruvi/

Please point me to some related API's to download all the files from such listings (if possible). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wget -r -l 1 http://url.example.com/directory/
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean programmatically from  Java you can look at the java.net.URL.connect method.  Here is an example of using it from the [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html), along with an [example of reading from a URL](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean programmatically? 
For starters, look at wget and a batch script.